# Why do kit wines age differently?

Tags: wine, kits

Most kit wines claim they're ready to drink in a month or two.  I've found they're much better at 6 months or so.  But when making wine from grapes, it seems everyone recommends aging at least a year, if not longer.  So what do kit winemakers do to make their wine drinkable earlier?

Comment: Because fewer people would buy them if they told the truth on the label -- that all wine needs to age a year before drinking.

Comment: I think that your kit wine would be even better at 12 months. Similarly, from-scratch wines would be drinkable after 6 months. So I don't think that kit wines age faster.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get to the last few bottles of a kit, maybe six months to a year after it was made, you'll kick yourself for drinking the others too early.  Wine needs time, simple answer to your question.  But as was stated earlier, its marketing, by the kit companies. I never had a kit that didnt improve with time.